# Error: undefined rows in Discord.js and Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, discord.js

I recently just switched over from MySQL to PostgreSQL in terms of Databases for my new Discord.js bot. I keep getting an the error saying that rows hbucks is undefined or not defined. The code is below.

```
module.exports = (bot, message, args, con) => {
  con.query(`SELECT * FROM hbucks WHERE id = '${message.author.id}' AND guildid = '${message.guild.id}'`, (err, rows) => { //Where id defines what row to use, this is stating that you are going to organize it by the id
  console.log(rows[0]);
  if(err) throw err;
  let sql;
  let username = message.author.username
  let authorid = [message.author.id]
  if(rows.length < 1) {
    sql = `INSERT INTO hbucks (id, hbucks, username, guildid) VALUES ('${authorid}', "${generateXp()}", ${con.escape(username)}, '${message.guild.id}')`
  } else {
    let hBucks = rows[0].hbucks;
    sql = `UPDATE hbucks SET hbucks = ${hBucks + generateXp()} WHERE id = '${authorid}' AND guildid = '${message.guild.id}'`;
    con.query(sql, console.log);
    sql = `UPDATE hbucks SET username = ${con.escape(username)} WHERE id = '${authorid}' AND guildid = '${message.guild.id}'`;
  }
  con.query(sql);
  }
);
```

And the error is let hBucks = rows[0].hbucks is undefined.
This code seemed to work and have no issues at all with MySQL

Comment: Could you post what rows[0] logs?

Comment: @Saddy rows: [object Object]

Comment: Strange, try console.log(JSON.stringify(rows[0]))

Comment: If it is too big to put in a comment you can edit your original post or send it in a https://hastebin.com

Comment: @Saddy It still is showing the same error.

Comment: It still logs [Object object]?

Comment: @Saddy Yep, I don't know why...

Comment: Hmm I may not be right but that could be because the object is empty. I have to leave for a little bit so in the meantime I would try looking up similar things and seeing if you can modify the object (add things etc)

Comment: @Saddy Ok np. If you have Discord and would like to chat with me because I am now getting warnings from this lol, my Discord is Vincent Lauro#1067

Comment: If it still returns `[Object object]` that means that you are trying to save an object directly into SQL. You need to do `JSON.stringify(object)` whenever you save to the database, and `JSON.parse(string)` when you fetch from the database!